# Finding an $L^2$-$L^2$ bound on the Bogovski Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

While looking at the Stokes operator in an online course I'm taking, we came across what is known as the Bogovski operator. It is used to show that, for $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ open, bounded, connected and with Lipschitz boundary, for every $f\in L^2(\Omega)$ with $\int f=0$ there exists $u\in H_0^1(\Omega;\mathbb{K}^n)=H_0^1(\Omega)^n$ such that $\text{div }u=f$.

The operator is defined likewise: let $\rho\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n)_+$ be a fixed non-negative test function such that $\int\rho=1$. Then for $f\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ we define
$$Bf(x):=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\int_1^\infty f(y)\rho(y+r(x-y))r^{n-1}(x-y)\ \mathrm{d}r\ \mathrm{d}y.$$
Using a change of variables one can show
$$Bf(x)=\int_{\mathbf{R}^n}\int_0^\infty f(x-z)\rho\left(x+s\frac{z}{|z|}\right)(s+|z|)^{n-1}\frac{z}{|z|^n}\ \mathrm{d}s\ \mathrm{d}z$$
from which we can deduce $Bf\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (we can use $g(s,z)=M\mathbf{1}_{B(0,2R)}(z)\mathbf{1}_{(0,2R)}(s)|z|^{1-n}$ as dominating function, where $M>0$ is a suitably large constant and $R>0$ is large enough that $f$ and $\rho$ both have support in $B(0,R)$). It is also possible to show that $Bf$ has compact support and that if $\int f=0$ then $\text{div }Bf=f$.

The exercise I am trying to attempt is to prove that there exists $c>0$ such that, if $f\in C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ satisfies $\int f=0$, then $\|Bf\|_2\le c\|f\|_2$. I am given the hint to use the dominating function $g$ mentioned above and either prove $L^1$-$L^1$ and $L^\infty$-$L^\infty$ bounds and interpolate using the Riesz-Thorin theorem, or use the fact that $\|\varphi_k* h\|_p\le\|h\|_p$ and $\varphi_k*h\to h$ in $L^p$, where $(\varphi_k)$ is an approximate identity of convolution, $1\le p<\infty$ and $h\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

I have tried both methods but without much luck. A hurdle I've been unable to overcome is that the dominating function $g$ necessarily depends on $f$ - I have been unable to find a suitable bound for the integrand of the second form of $Bf$ which does not depend on the support of $f$. I also am unsure where to use the condition that $\int f=0$. Does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: Crucially, I had misread the question as $f\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$, not $f\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$. I have come up with a solution, but if anyone would like to have a go before I share it that is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone is interested in this problem, I have written a solution. It ended up not being all that difficult once I realised the question specified $f\in C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ (where $\Omega$ is open and bounded) rather than $f\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^n)$.

Let $R>0$ be large enough that both $\Omega$ and the support of $\rho$ are contained in $B(0,R)$. For any $x\in\Omega$, if $s\ge2R$ then $\rho(x+s\frac{z}{|z|})=0$ and if $|z|\ge2R$ then $f(x-z)=0$. For $s\in(0,2R)$ and $z\in B(0,2R)$ we have $(s+|z|)^{n-1}\le2^{n-2}(s^{n-1}+|z|^{n-1})\le(2R)^{n-1}$, so we find
\begin{align*}
|Bf(x)|&\le\int\int_0^\infty|f(x-z)|\rho\left(x+s\frac{z}{|z|}\right)\mathbf1_{(0,2R)}(s)\mathbf1_{B(0,2R)}(z)(s+|z|)^{1-n}\ \mathrm d s\ \mathrm d z\\
&\le(2R)^n\|\rho\|_\infty\int_{B(0,2R)}|f(x-z)||z|^{1-n}\ \mathrm d z.
\end{align*}
Setting $M:=(2R)^n\|\rho\|_\infty$, this gives us an $L^\infty$-$L^\infty$ bound:
$$\|Bf\|_\infty\le\left(M\int_{B(0,2R)}|z|^{1-n}\ \mathrm d z\right)\|f\|_\infty$$
and integrating over $x\in\Omega$ gives us an $L^1$-$L^1$ bound:
\begin{align*}
\|Bf\|_1&\le M\int_\Omega\int_{B(0,2R)}|f(x-z)||z|^{1-n}\ \mathrm d z\ \mathrm d x\\
&=M\int_{B(0,2R)}\left(\int_\Omega|f(x-z)|\ \mathrm d x\right)|z|^{1-n}\ \mathrm d z\\
&\le\left(M\int_{B(0,2R)}|z|^{1-n}\ \mathrm d z\right)\|f\|_1.
\end{align*}
To verify that $c:=M\int_{B(0,2R)}|z|^{1-n}\ \mathrm d z$ is finite, convert to polar coordinates:
\begin{align*}
z_1&=r\cos\phi_1,\\
z_2&=r\sin\phi_1\cos\phi_2,\\
\vdots\\
z_{n-1}&=r\sin\phi_1\ldots\sin\phi_{n-2}\cos\phi_{n-1},\\
z_n&=r\sin\phi_1\ldots\sin\phi_{n-2}\sin\phi_{n-1}
\end{align*}
and note that the Jacobian of the transformation is $r^{n-1}F(\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_{n-2})$ for some continuous (and bounded) function $F$. It hence follows by the Riesz-Thorin Theorem that $\|Bf\|_2\le c\|f\|_2$ for all $f\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$.